# If I get 15 mins interval data for predicting a hourly target, should I use 15 mins data or aggregate to 1 hr data for training?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, regression

I got the following datasets, and the data is in 15 mins interval:

```
Time                A   B    A+B
2021-01-01 00:00    10  20   30
2021-01-01 00:15    20  30   50
2021-01-01 00:30    30  40   70
2021-01-01 01:00    40  50   90
2021-01-01 01:00    10  20   30
2021-01-01 01:15    20  30   50
2021-01-01 01:30    30  40   70
2021-01-01 02:00    40  50   90
```

Basically I need to develop a machine learning model for predicting the hourly A+B

```
Time                A+B
2021-01-02 00:00    
2021-01-02 01:00    
2021-01-02 02:00    
2021-01-02 03:00
```

I want to ask when selecting my target label for my training model

1. Should I use 15 mins data for training and add the result afterward for hourly A+B or should I aggregate the 15 mins data into hourly data for training? What is the difference?
2. Is there any difference if I try to train A and B separately and add them up comparing with training A+B directly?

Thanks a lot

Comment: So you want to predict A+B with only the timestamp or are there other datapoints involved?

Comment: only the hourly data point, e.g. 00:00, 01:00, 02:00 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution. Since you care about the hour total and you get data every 15 mins I would give the 15 minute interval data for a whole hour as the input to the network. Then the output would be the final value at the end of that hour.

so for example the input the net would be shape [4,2] this would be the A and B values. The output will be the final result after the hour.

On another note this doesn't sound like a problem that needs machine learning but I'm sure there is more info i dont know about

Answer (score 0):

I would first split the data into a training and validation set as-is.

Then take a third option of using a sliding window of 1 hour over the samples in each set to produce data at one hour intervals.  This will create 3x more valid training samples than simple aggregating.

Whether to build a model of A, B or A+B depends on what you want to predict.  Do you need predictions for A and B separately? or do you only need A+B?  If you only want A+B, then build the model around that.  Any basic ML model will be able to handle the summation, so it will likely not make significant difference. As with most data-driven problems, it will depend on the data, so if you really want to find out if there is a difference for your data, you may want to try both, and compare results on a hold-out set.